# How show Podman container stats with glances?

Tags: monitoring, container, podman

I installed glances via pip and it does not show Podman containers. Docker container however are shown when I run glances with sudo. Docker is run as root, Podman run rootless.
I changed my glances.conf [containers] section to:

```
[containers]
disable=False
# Only show specific containers (comma separated list of container name or regular expression)
# Comment this line to display all containers (default configuration)
#show=telegraf
# Hide some containers (comma separated list of container name or regular expression)
# Comment this line to display all containers (default configuration)
#hide=telegraf
# Define the maximum docker size name (default is 20 chars)
max_name_size=20
#cpu_careful=50
# Thresholds for CPU and MEM (in %)
cpu_warning=70
cpu_critical=90
#mem_careful=20
mem_warning=50
mem_critical=70
#
# Per container thresholds
#containername_cpu_careful=10
#containername_cpu_warning=20
#containername_cpu_critical=30
#
# By default, Glances only display running containers
# Set the following key to True to display all containers
all=True
# Define Podman sock
podman_sock=unix:///run/user/1000/podman/podman.sock
```

I confirmed the changes in this config file work. Is the path to my podman socket not correct? How can I find my podman socket?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you started podman socket? You can verify that by running `systemctl --user status podman.socket`.
If you want to start socket just run `systemctl --user start podman.socket`